# Access 'About this Mac' before creating a user

Tags: terminal, mac, recovery, system-profiler

I've wiped and reinstalled macOS in order to sell a 2017 MacBook Pro. Of course, I forgot to take a screenshot of 'About This Mac' to get all the specifics (all I need is the CPU variant).

I've booted into Recovery Mode to access terminal and try a host of variations on `system_profiler`. None of them work.

I don't want to have to create a user just to view my specs and then have to wipe and reinstall macOS again.

Does anyone have a working 2020 method for accessing system information from the terminal *before* creating a user?

Comment: Did you check whether there is an "About my Mac" menu entry in Recovery Mode?

Comment: Did you try using `sysctl`?  Use the command `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.brand_string`

Comment: @nohillside there is no entry for that, only a Startup Disk option (which I tried and still doesn't show about my Mac)

Comment: @Allan I've tried a different version which didn't include grep , but your version works , thanks very much!

Comment: If you have an external drive to boot from, you can take screenshots of About This Mac there.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sysctl` command to get the CPU brand string.

```
% sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
machdep.cpu.brand_string: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-700K CPU @ 4.20GHz
```

Comment: Hi, your other suggestion worked:
sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.brand_string

Comment: Both should work, with and without the `grep`